# Firebase Cloud Function Unauthenticated Error After Password Sign-Up

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am receiving the following error when triggering this cloud function: "Error unauthenticated".

I do not wish to allow unauthenticated calls to this cloud function.

The workflow is as follows:

1. User registers in app via firebase password authentication
2. Firebase Auth Credentials are created (firebase signs in user upon success)
3. Once the credentials have been created, the cloud function is triggered in the firebase auth callback.

At this point, the call should be authenticated, given it's being triggered in the firebase auth response.

However, it keeps erroring with

> Error: unauthenticated

The user is authenticated at this point.

Any suggestions?
CLIENT CODE ->

```js
const onRegisterPress = () => {
  if (password !== confirmPassword) {
    alert("Passwords don't match.")
    return
  }
  setLoading(true);
  //CREATE'S USER'S AUTH CREDENTIALS
  firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((response) => {
      const data = {
        ...
      }
      //console.log(response);
      return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {
        await firebase.functions().httpsCallable('writeAccountUser')({
          data
        }).then((response) => {
          console.log("Write Account User Response: ", response);
          resolve(setLoading(false));
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.error("Cloud Function Error: ", error);
          setLoading(false);
          reject(error)
        })
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      alert(error)
    });
}
```

CLOUD FUNCTION ->

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
const firestore = admin.firestore();

exports.writeAccountUser = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    console.log("Incoming Data: ", data);
    console.log("Incoming Context: ", context);
    const clientData = data.data;
    console.log("Client Data: ", clientData);
    console.log("Account ID: ", clientData.accountID);
    return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
        const accountsRef = firestore.collection('Accounts');
        const usersRef = firestore.collection('users');
        const now = new Date();
        if (clientData.accountExists === true) {
            console.log("Account Exists");
            await accountsRef
                .doc(clientData.accountID)
                .update({
                    users: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(clientData.uid)
                }).catch((error) => { console.error(error); reject(false) });
        }
        else {
            console.log("Account Does Not Exist!");
            const account_data = clientData.accountData;
            const product_lines = clientData.productLines;
            await accountsRef
                .doc(clientData.accountID)
                .set({
                    account_data,
                    product_lines,
                    users: [clientData.uid],
                    dateCreated: {
                        date: now,
                        timestamp: now.getTime()
                    }
                }).catch((error) => { console.error(error); reject(false)});
        };
        const email = clientData.email;
        const fullName = clientData.fullName;
        const acceptTerms = clientData.acceptTerms;
        const userData = {
            id: clientData.uid,
            email,
            fullName,
            accountID: clientData.accountID,
            dateCreated: {
                date: now,
                timestamp: now.getTime()
            },
            lastUpdateFetch: {
                date: now,
                timestamp: now.getTime()
            },
            termsConditionsAccepted: acceptTerms
        };

        await usersRef
            .doc(clientData.uid)
            .set(userData)
            .catch((error) => { console.error(error); reject(false) });
        resolve(true);
    });
});
```

Error ->
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: unauthenticated]
at node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/rn/prebuilt.rn-f9cd27ba.js:12199:33 in 
at http:///node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:169743:29 in _errorForResponse
at node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/rn/prebuilt.rn-f9cd27ba.js:12747:31 in yu
at node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:77:12 in 
at http://REDACTED/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:120748:21 in 
at http://REDACTED/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:120702:31 in fulfilled

Answer (score 1):

You can try refactoring the function as shown below:

```
const onRegisterPress = async () => {
  if (password !== confirmPassword) {
    alert("Passwords don't match.")
    return
  }
  setLoading(true);

  const response = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

  const data = {...}
 
  const fnResponse = await firebase.functions().httpsCallable('writeAccountUser')({data})

  console.log("Write Account User Response: ", response);
}
```

You can also create the account using the Admin SDK in the same function and log the user on your web app after the response. That'll ensure the Cloud function's action has been executed as well (just in case the function is not called after user sign up for any reason).

Comment: I like this, it is a lot cleaner.

It is still showing [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: unauthenticated]

I am trying to write to a collection within Firestore via the Admin SDK in this cloud function. I originally write to it on the client with the security the following security rules: "allow read,write: if request.auth.token!=null" as a test, calling it directly within the firebase createUser callback and it worked. What's odd is it's not authenticating for the cloud function.

Comment: @Arcade336 can you share your Cloud function code? If you are Admin SDK you should not get any auth errors.

Comment: I have updated the thread to include the cloud function code. Thank you for taking a look at and responding to my question.

Comment: I believe the auth error I am receiving pertains to invoking the cloud function vs the cloud function writing to firestore via the Admin SDK.

Comment: @Arcade336 the user does seem to be logged in before calling the function. Can you share a screenshot of error along with it's error stack so we know where it's coming from? Is the function being triggered at first place?

Comment: I updated the thread to include the error trace. Given the error is stating "Unauthenticated", it is preventing the cloud function from being triggered at all.

Comment: @Arcade336 the error seems to be from Firebase client SDK (Firestore), are you using Firestore somewhere else? Do you have any `onAuthStateChanged` observer that is possibly redirecting user after sign up somewhere else where Firestore is used ?

Comment: I have an onAuthStateChanged observer on the main thread that updates the user document within firestore with the device ID upon the user logging in. This can't complete because the document doesn't exist (the user document is created within the cloud function).

What doesn't make sense is the cloud function not firing off even though the user is authenticated at the point where it is called.

Comment: @Arcade336 so you are running in to a race condition. I would just unsubscribe from the auth observer, pass all the device ID along with data and add everything from Cloud function. So now we are not expecting cloud function to complete before anything else does.